# yii2:autofill on multiple condtions

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have models/tables as follows:

table room_category

```
id room_category
1   Classic
2   Deluxe
```

table room_charges

```
id room_category room_name room_charges
1        1             c1       600
2        2             d1       800
```

table ipd_charges

```
id    doctor   room_category    charges_cash charges_cashless
1        1          1              200            300
2        1          2              300            400
```

table patient_detail(patient_admission)

```
id patient_name tpa_name(if not null, equivalent to charges_cashless)
1        1        Null
2        2         1
```

table daily_ward_entry

```
id  patient_name  room_name(id)  doctor_name(id) charges ( from ipd_charges)
1          1           1           1              200
2          2           2           1              400
```

Now there is a dropdown field in daily_ward_entry table for doctor. When I select the drop-down field the charges field needs to be autofilled.

I achieve this using Jason and ajax with the following code without taking into account the room_category. but the charges vary for room_category.(this is only working after saving the record, I prefer if there is someway to pull the charges before save.)

Here is my code in the controller:

```
public function actionChargesCash($id){
        $model = \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['doctor'=>$id]);
        return \yii\helpers\Json::encode(['visit_charges'=>$model->charges_cash]); 
    }

    public function actionChargesCashLess($id){
        $model= \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['doctor'=>$id]);
        return \yii\helpers\Json::encode(['visit_charges'=>$model->charges_cashless]); 
    }
```

I have also tried this variaton:

```
public function actionChargesCash($id){
        $model = \app\models\IpdCharges::find()
                ->where(['doctor'=>$id]) 
                 ->andwhere(['room_category'=>'daily_ward_entry.room_name'])->one();
```

If I replace the `'daily_ward_entry.room_name'` with room_name id like 3 or 6, I am getting the result, which means I am not using the correct syntax for referring the column from current table.

How can I include the condition for room_name in the above code?
Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `daily_ward_entry.room_name`? `daily_ward_entry.room_name` should be replaced with value. Actually, `daily_ward_entry.room_name` is totally meaningless.

Comment: Hi Ali, there is a column room_name in table daily_ward_entry and I want to compare it with room_category in ipd_charges room_category as the doctor charges vary with the room_category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`daily_ward_entry.room_name` is meaningless without any relation or join or sub-query. Actually, the query does not know the `daily_ward_entry`.

Suggestions:

1- Create a relation and use `with` or `Join With`

2- Create a query with `Join` of  `daily_ward_entry` and `ipd_charges` on `room_name=room_category`

3- Create a query with a sub-query, to find all|one IpdCharge(s) that have `room_category` in `SELECT room_name FROM daily_ward_entry`

All of above suggestions satisfy your requirements.

**Another important note:**

- `andWhere()`/`orWhere()` are to apply where to the default condition.
- `where()` is to ignore the default condition

I don't see any default condition (Overridden `Find()`), So, there is no need to use `andWhere`, Just:

```
where(['doctor'=>$id,'room_category'=>3,...])
```

Would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi Ali - I have tried with join also like 
`$model = \app\models\IpdCharges::find()
                 ->innerjoin('daily_ward_entry', 
                'daily_ward_entry.room_name =  ipd_charges.room_category')
                ->where(['doctor'=>$id])
                 ->andwhere(['room_category'=>'daily_ward_entry.room_name'])->one();`
but I am getting a null result

Comment: Hi Ali - I need to use the field/column name in place of `=>3...` How I can do that

Comment: @Pawan Hi, where(['doctor'=>$id,'room_category'=>3,'Column'=>'value','Column'=>'Value',...])

Comment: Dear Ali - really I feeling dumb, I can't understand how to use that, I want to pull the data from current table i.e. `daily_ward_entry.room_name` to be compared against `room_category`

Comment: OK Dear Ali - I will try with ur other suggestions and see what happens. Thanks for your help.